# Java - how to parse both json arrays and objects

Tags: java, android, json, org.json

i am using the `org.json` package in Java (Android) and I am just stumbled with a simple problem.

The webserver returns an array if everything is okay, but an json object `{ error : true, ...}` if something went wrong.

How can I parse that into a common object - I mean both arrays and objects are json after all, but it seems `JSONArray` and `JSONOBject` don't share an interface in common.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSONTokener.nextValue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue%28%29) and check if the result is a JSONObject or a JSONArray (using instanceof).

Comment: Nice, didn't know that class.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is ... fix the webserver and have it return a consistant result. Otherwise, you basically are going to have to manually inspect the returned data to see what it is.

Another option is catching the `JSONException` the constructor for `JSONArray` will throw when it isn't an array which would indicate to you that you should try `JSONObject`.

Comment: i worked with jquery a lot before, so that was never a problem, and i think as long as the server returns proper json, then this is okay.

Comment: It's "ok" in that it is valid JSON. From a *design perspective* it's poor, which is precisely why you've having to jump through hoops in a language that *isn't* dynamically typed (and even in one that is you are still dealing with two different types). If an object was returned an object in both cases, these problems go away.